# Having Difficulty Using MongoDb C# Driver's Sample()

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am trying to get some random items from the database using the [Sample()](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/commit/bd0383d66be2a76648968fbafaa36bf99c258b2d) method. I updated to the latest version of the driver and copied the using statements from the linked example. However, something isn't working, and I am hoping it's some simple mistake on my part. All the relevant information is in the image below:

[image]

Edit:

Greg, I read the aggregation docs [here](https://docs.mongodb.org/getting-started/csharp/aggregation/) and the raw db method [doc here](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sample/), but I still don't get it. Last two lines are my attempts, I have never used aggregation before:

```
            var mongoCollection = GetMongoCollection<BsonDocument>(collectionName);
            long[] locationIds = new long[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
            var locationsArray = new BsonArray();
            foreach (long l in locationIds) { locationsArray.Add(l); };
            FilterDefinition<BsonDocument> sampleFilter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.In("LocationId", locationsArray);
            var findSomething = mongoCollection.Find(sampleFilter); //this works, the two attempts below don't.
            var aggregateSomething = mongoCollection.Aggregate(sampleFilter).Sample(25);
            var aggregateSomething2 = mongoCollection.Aggregate().Match(sampleFilter).Sample(25);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sample is only available from an aggregation.  You need to start with Aggregate, not Find.  I believe it's also available in Linq.

UPDATE:
Looks like we don't have a method for it specifically. However, you can use the AppendStage method.

```
mongoCollection.Aggregate(sampleFilter)
               .AppendStage<BsonDocument>("{ $sample: { size: 3 } }");
```

Comment: Craig, any chance that you could give me an example? I tried looking for the "CreateQuery()" function you use, hoping it would have an aggregation example, but I am not finding it.